# Aws Cognito Bearer Token : Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, bearer-token

I am working on aws cognito with bearer token.
Below is the code to setup Bearer configuration.
[image]

I have written code to login via user name & password
[image]

I am able to logged in successfully and get the token
But when i am trying to access my authorise API it is throwing below error.
[image]

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your system is failing when trying to download OpenID Connect metadata. This will be a URL such as the following - so you should make sure your API is configured with a URL you can reach in the browser:

- https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_qqJgVeuTn/.well-known/openid-configuration

The following type of code should work when validating Cognito tokens in .NET, if you add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` library. Note that Cognito does not issue an Audience claim so you need to avoid validating it:

```cs
services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.Authority = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_qqJgVeuTn";
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters {
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = false,
    };
  });
```

Note that this includes a website library in APIs and expected OpenID Connect endpoints to exist. Personally I prefer not to write OAuth secured APIs like this.

**JWKS ENDPOINT**

The standard way to do API token validation is for the API to only know about the JWKS endpoint, as in these examples:

- [Node.js API JWT Validation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts#L40)
- [Java API JWT Validation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java#L54)

I found this approach a little harder in .NET, where libraries didn't quite do what I wanted. Here is some code that shows how to use extensibility points, in case useful:

- [.NET API JWT Validation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.cs#L38)

Comment: The link to the code of yours is dead. 404 and a brown figure throwing up its hands in the air...

Comment: Fixed that - try it now

Comment: I surely will. Meantime, I actually figured out the issue. In my case (and it may vary for others), it was **explicitly** setting `Authority` in the options for the bearer to an adress that didn't provide the *.well-known-config* discopoint. It doesn't matter whether (or how) the issuer is set in the validation options nor if `ValidateIssuer` is turned off. It's a very rare case but the general conclusion would suggest that absence of the endpoint with *.well-known/openid-configuration* is the reason for that error message. Immensely misleading and very non-apparent.